# Does ASP.NET Core SignalR or SignalR Java client have an issue with sending or receiving null values?

Tags: android, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I am creating a multiplayer card game. I use ASP.NET Core SignalR for full duplex communication with an Android client written in Java. On Android I use the SignalR Java client library.

For some communication I find it natural to just use signalR for synchronous request-response type of thing. SignalR allows for such as exampled below.

```
public async Task<string> GetString(){ return "foo"; }
```

This works as intended. I can invoke the server method from Android and get a response either blocking or via a callback.

Now to the problem. I have scenarios where I find it suitable to return a `null` object from the SignalR method.

```
public async Task<GameState?> GetGameState(string gameName){
    if (gameIsCanceled) return null;
    else return new ProperGameState();
}
```

In this kind of scenario it seems like the case where I return an actual game state object works fine. But the cases in which I return `null` nothing is returned.

```
Single<String> stringPromise = hubConnection.invoke(String.class, "GetRunningGame");
String runningGameName =  stringPromise.blockingGet();
```

Above is like the invokation looks in Android. It does not get pass the `blockingGet()`

Anyone come across this or got any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: It's a bug with how the java client handles nulls. Feel free to file an issue on the product at https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore